# How to compress an ISO file

Tags: windows, software-rec, iso-image

Does anybody know of any software which will allow me to compress an ISO. file?

Answer (score 7):

If you are just aiming to compress it for moving, then [7-Zip](http://www.7-zip.org/) or another decent file compressor is what you're aiming for, just don't expect them to do too much as often the contents of ISOs are already compressed (plus it can take a REALLY long time to try and compress huge ISOs for little to no gain)

For playing around with it and keeping it as an ISO, I'd suggest checking out [MagicISO](http://www.magiciso.com/) as it has an "ISO Compression/Decompression" system in the newer versions ([see here](http://www.magiciso.com/tutorials/miso-compressiso.htm)) that may help you out.

Comment: ISOs may or may contain compressed data, but the format itself is not compressed.

Comment: Remember, some compression containers (like windows built-in zip) have limitations on file size. Make sure your compressed files decompress OK if they are over the 2GB or 4GB magical barriers.

Comment: I would add that PowerISO also support a compressible image format (.daa) which you can load as a virtual drive letter (a feature of poweriso).

Answer (score 1):

Any compression software will compress an iso file.

zip

bzip2

7zip

rar

etc.

However, I suspect you want something more... like compress the iso file bust have it still be an iso compatible image?

For that, I don't that that is doable.

Comment: to make an iso of compressed data, first compress the data, then make the iso.  any of the compression tools you mention can compress the data.

Answer (score 0):

I think what would be blank space (and thus zeroing would be a win) on a HD image, but I bet a CD has none, and probably just automatically files the empty space at the end of files with 0 anyways.

So no, 7zip is probably your best bet if you want to save space.

Answer (score 0):

MagicISO supports Universal Image Format (UIF) which supports compression and encryption. Although compressed, the image is still mountable.

http://www.magiciso.com/tutorials/miso-whatuif.htm