# How to control the size of a .iso image

Tags: iso-image

Is there anyway to control the size of an ISO image when creating it from a CD without having to compress it? I'm trying to make a bootable ISO image.I'm  using ImgBurn to make a win7 image from a CD

Comment: I'm using ImgBurn to make win7, but I'm trying to keep the door open for other sotware and windows releases

Comment: I found this - http://superuser.com/questions/100940/how-to-compress-an-iso-file I'm used to Mac, which would use a compressed .dmg format rather than .iso, but I don't think that's an option for Windows

Answer (score 0):

No. The iso format is uncompressed. If you want a smaller iso, put less data in the image.

For a Windows 7 image, there are some tools to reduce what components are included in the image such as [nLite](http://www.nliteos.com), which I have used to slipstream drivers, updates, and service packs into an image. The developer seems to have a more updated release called [NTLite](https://www.ntlite.com/). A quick search has shown there are howto guides like on [howtogeek](http://www.howtogeek.com/124368/how-to-create-a-customized-windows-7-installation-disc-with-integrated-updates) that uses another tool I haven't used before. But if you want a standard image, possibly including some additional drivers, or more recent updates included, no the image will only be bigger.

Comment: Would you suggest any tools for me? Any tutorials?

Comment: @SamIbraheem added a couple of links to my answer

Comment: [RTSevenLite is good for reducing image size](http://www.softpedia.com/get/System/Boot-Manager-Disk/RT-Seven-Lite.shtml)